# Finite abelian group of type S must be $G=H\times H$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In the following paper by Delaunay http://delaunay.perso.math.cnrs.fr/heuristics_2.pdf, it is claimed that a finite abelian group comes with a unique non-degenerate alternating bilinear pairing

$$\beta: G \times G \rightarrow \Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$$

iff $G=H\times H$. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ has such a pairing $\beta$ and write $G = C_{d_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus C_{d_k}$, where each $d_i|d_{i+1}$. We prove by induction on $k$ that $G \cong H \times H$ for some group $H$. The result is true for $k=0$ with $H$ trivial, so assume that $k>0$.

If $d_{k-1} \ne d_k$ then, letting $x$ be the generator of the final direct summand $C_{d_k}$, it is not hard show that $\beta(g,d_{k-1}x) =0$ for all $g \in G$, contradicting $\beta$ being non-degenerate.

Let $x$ and $y$ be generators of the final two direct summands $C_{d_k}$. Non-degeneracy of $\beta$ implies that $\beta(x,y)$ has order $d_k$, so we can assume that $\beta(x,y) = 1/d_k + {\mathbb Z}$. Also, for a generator $z$ of one of the other direct summands of $G$, the orders of $\beta(z,x)$ and $\beta(z,y)$ must divide $d_k$, so they are equal to $a/d_k + {\mathbb Z}$ and $b/d_k + {\mathbb Z}$ for some $a,b \in \{0,1,\ldots,d_k-1\}$. Then, by replacing $z$ by $z -bx + ay$, we can assume that $\beta(z,x)=\beta(z,y)=0$.

Suppose that the restriction of $\beta$ to the subgroup $K := C_{d_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus C_{d_{k-2}}$ is degenerate. Then there exists $g \in K$ with $\beta(g,h) = 0$ for all $h \in K$. Now, since the orders of $\beta(g,x)$ and $\beta(g,y)$ must divide $d_k$, there exist $a,b \in \{0,1,\ldots,d_k-1\}$ with $\beta(g,x) = a/d_k + {\mathbb Z}$ and $\beta(g,y) = b/d_k + {\mathbb Z}$. So, putting, $g' = g - bx + ay$, we have $\beta(g',h)=0$ for all $h \in G$, contradicting non-degeneracy of $\beta$.

So  the restriction of $\beta$ to $K$ is non-degenerate and the result follows by induction applied to $K$.

Comment: In the third paragraph, do you mean order $d_k$?

Comment: Yes, thanks, and in many other places. I've corrected it.

Comment: Dear @DerekHolt, I am not sure to fully understand the claim « Then, by replacing $z$ by $z -bx + ay$, we can assume that $\beta(z,x)=\beta(z,y)=0$. » Indeed, the element $z-bx+ay$ does not even lie in one of the other direct summands $C_{d_i}$ of $G$ (with $i \leq k-2$) in general, so it is not a generator of $C_{d_i}$ (while $z$ is, by definition, a generator of $C_{d_i}$).

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem. The direct summands are not unique. $z-bx+ay$ might not generate one of the original direct summands, but it generates a  cyclic group of order $d_i$ which can replace the existing summand. For examples if $G = C_4 \oplus C_4 \oplus C_4$ with generators $z,x,y$, then we could replace $z$ by $z-2x-y$.

Comment: Dear @DerekHolt, I am grateful to your kind reply. Then, if I understood well, the subgroup K from your 4th paragraph is defined using the "new" generators from the end of the 3rd paragraph. 
$\tag*{}$
 Similarly, in the 3rd paragraph, I think that $y$ is _chosen_ so that $\beta(x,y)$ has order $d_k$ (after having fixed $x$). I don't think that _any_ generator $y$ of $C_{d_k}$ ensures that $\beta(x,y)$ has order $d_k$ (but I might have missed something). 
Anyway, thank you!