# Existence of non-degenerate alternating pairing $ \psi : A \times A \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} $ and perfect square cardinality

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, representation-theory, characters, arithmetic-geometry

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group, and let

$ \psi : A \times A \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} $

be an alternating, non-degenerate bilinear form on $A$.

To prove $A$ have square cardinality, [Non-degenerate alternating bilinear form on a finite abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27579/non-degenerate-alternating-bilinear-form-on-a-finite-abelian-group)
gives one approach.

On the other hand, lemma 4 of [https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0998-10.pdf](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0998-10.pdf) gives another kind of explanation as the following.

Let $S$ be the subgroup of $A$ such that $\psi(s,s')=0$ for all $s,s'\in S$ and $S$ is maximal with respect to this property. Since $\psi(1,1)=0$, there is at least one subgroup with the property. Consider the character $X_a(s)=\psi(a,s)$ of $A$ for each $a\in A$. They are all distinc, since the pairing $\psi(a,s)$ is non-degenerate. Consider $A/S$. For each $a\in A/S$, we have a character of $S$ defined by $X_a(s)=\psi(a,s)$. By the definition of $S$, they are distinct.
**Therefore**, $\hat{S} \cong A/S$. Therefore, $A\cong S×\hat{S}$.

Why '**Therefore**, $\hat{S} \cong A/S$' holds ?
We constructed characters on $A/S$ and know that they are all distinct. However, I am now stuck on how to deduce $\hat{S} \cong A/S$ from these ingredients. From these ingredients, there is a injective map from $A/S$ to $\hat{S}$, but I'm stuck with proving that is surjective. In other words, why character on $S$ comes from the character on $A/S$ ?
Thank you for your help.

**P.S
In sb945's answer, the problem is subjectivity of  $c \mapsto X_c(s)$.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a\in A/S$ takes the form $c+s'$, where $s'\in S, c\in C$ and $C\oplus S=A$

then $$\psi(a,s)=\psi(c+s',s)=\psi(c,s)+\underbrace{\psi(s',s)}_{=0}=\psi(c,s)=X_c(s)$$
hence $c\mapsto X_c(s)$ is the isomorphism from $C$ (which is $A/S$) to $\widehat S$

You may think of $\psi$ as symplectic forms and $S$ as Lagrangians to get insights.

Comment: Why is  your map surjective ?